# Restore graphic after scroll panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox, invalidation

I'm using C# for developing a simple tool that has a picturebox inside a panel. The panel has property Autoscroll = true. If the Image of that picturebox is larger than the panel the panel has scrollbars

I could draw a rectangle on paint event of picturebox. But when i scroll, this rectangle disappears. I know it need to repaint it after moving the scrollbar but i don't know how to restore it again.

x, y, width, heigth, zoom is global variable and when use click in to treenode, it'll have data.

```
private void pictureBoxView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (choose == true)
            {
                Size newSize = new Size((int)(pictureBoxView.Image.Width * zoom),
                                       (int)(pictureBoxView.Image.Height * zoom));
                Graphics graphic = pictureBoxView.CreateGraphics();
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
                graphic.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, width, height);
                pen.Dispose();
            }
        }


 private void treeViewTemplate_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            // refresh picturebox
            pictureBoxView.Refresh();

            // allow repaint
            choose = true;

            string[] value = treeViewTemplate.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString().Split(',');
            x = Int32.Parse(value[0]);
            y = Int32.Parse(value[1]);
            width = Int32.Parse(value[2]);
            height = Int32.Parse(value[3]);
            zoom = Double.Parse(value[4]);

            //MessageBox.Show("x = " + y + ", y = " + y + ", width = " + width + ", height = " + height + ", zoom = " + zoom);

            // This call draw a rectangle again when I choose a value from TreeNode's Tag

            pictureBoxView_Paint(this, null);
        }
```

Comment: Or simply is how to draw a rectangle on picture box even when panel is repainted?

Answer (score 1):

you also can use pictureBoxView.Refresh()

and define two local variable save the scroll offset through ScrollEventArgs.NewValue

if you do not want to paint when scrolling, you can use this

`private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{ pictureBox1.Refresh();}`

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is good way, same to yBee's solution. Hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use `Invalidate` method in order to redraw a surface of the control:

```
pictureBoxView.Invalidate();
```

Here is a sample of redrawing a `PictureBox` that is inside a `Panel`:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rectangle);
}

private void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

The fixed red rectangle is redrawed when panel is scrolled.

Comment: Thank millions pro. If you don't show me this way, I don't know how to make it done.

Answer (score 0):

In this case (`PictureBox` in Panel control), you must create a method, which drawing on teh picture box. And you puts the drawing method in the Panel `ScrollEvent`.

```
private void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Drawing();
    }
```